# Getting errors after updating Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I tried updating `Xamarin Forms` to a version starting with a `2` for quite some time now. I believe i have tried everything ive found online so thats why i am here.

After updating `Xamarin Forms` and building in `Visual Studio` I get the following warning + 3 errors (all these warnings/errors are for my .droid project btw):

```
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly. //on iOS
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\User\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.0.1.jar doesn't exist.            
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\./ doesn't exist.
```

Then, after building again, i start getting these errors:

35 Times this:

```
 Error      error: package android.support.v4.widget.X does not exist
```

8 times this:

```
Error       error: method Activate in class TypeManager cannot be applied to given types
```

8 times this:

```
Error       error: cannot find symbol
```

plus these 4:

```
Error       error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
Error       error: cannot access SupportMenu
Error       error: cannot access NestedScrollingParent
Error       error: cannot access ActionProvider
```

Additionally i also still get the iOS warning from earlier.
If i clean and build again at this point, the original 4 messages reappear, and so the circle keeps on going...

I am seriously at wits end right now and i appreciate any help you can give me.
This ive tried: 
Pretty much everything from this thread:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32346/install-android-support-library-available-in-sdk-installer-error-doesnt-leave-us

and everything from here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57658/cannot-get-vs-2015-to-build-when-upgrading-to-xamarin-forms-v2-0-0-6490

Plus I have tried a bunch of other things that i am probably forgetting right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XamlC Task errors occur when you upgrade to XF 2.0.1 and 2.1.0 due to new build targets.

They are solved by a simple restart of Visual Studio.

The dll's used by another process sometimes occurs when VS locks on the files aren't correctly released. The only solution to this is to go through all your bin and obj files. Delete them all, then close all instances of VS and start again.

With your Android issues, did you do a complete upgrade on all packages as you aren't meant to with Android Support packages. You will notice Xamarin wants the exact version 23.0.1.3 - don't upgrade to the higher versions. If you have downgrade them.

As for the files it says it can't find at the top. Go to those directories and delete the directories themselves. VS will redownload and rebuild them if they are cleaned out.

Comment: Thats about it from my suggestion standpoint. Normally that routine sorts out my Android issues.

Comment: Wow, deleting \AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\ actually worked. Thank you so very much!